# How to display a placeholder in all pages even though it is not configured to do so?

Tags: sitecore

I have following placeholders in the layout

- header-placeholder
- top-back-placeholder
- center-placeholder
- bottom-back-placeholder
- footer-placeholder

and following Items using the above layout

- Home Item - Used to display Home page
- Article Item - Used to display Article Page

Here the two back placeholders used in the above layout is used to display a back button in the top and bottom of the page(Here I will be configuring the same sublayout for two different placeholders to show the back buttons in top and bottom) but these back button should be shown only in Article page and not in Home Page.

So I am configuring accordingly for only Article Item(Using Presentation -> Details option) and not for Home Item.But However in the edit mode I am able to see an empty portion containg Back placeholders asking for Back Sublayouts in the top and bottom of the Home page, though I have not configured it in the Presentation->Details of the Home Item.

Please let me know the setting that I am missing which is showing the placeholders in the Home Page even though it is not configured to show.

Comment: Do you mean that you see it while in Page Editor mode?

Answer (score 3):

You have set it up correctly, but seem to be a bit confused about placeholders versus sublayouts and renderings.

Placeholders are just areas that CAN be used to contain sublayouts and/or renderings. A placeholder can contain 0 or many sublayouts and renderings.

In your example:-
The placeholders still exist on the layout for the Home item. Without assigning a sublayout or rendering to that placeholder (as done on the Home item), nothing will fill that place on the page.

In edit mode (page editor mode I assume), you'll see the area for those placeholders with nothing in them, as Sitecore is just allowing you to place something in there if you want. 
(i.e it's showing you that a placeholder is there for you to fill with a sublayout or rendering, but nothing is in it at the moment.)

If you'd like to remove the placeholder from the layout just for the home item, you could have some code-behind in the layout to do the following:-

Give the placeholder an ID (like topBackPlaceholder).

```
if (Sitecore.Context.Item.Paths.FullPath == Sitecore.Context.Site.RootPath)
{
    topBackPlaceholder.Visible = false;
}
```